# how to invoke autogen on cygwin terminal to generate ./configure

Tags: bash, cygwin

I want to build configuration files using `./configure` which is missing in downloaded software project(here: xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4).

Hence I want to use autogen(On cygwin terminal should I use autogen.sh or autogen.exe). What is the correct path of autogen.sh that is used to generate ./configure. When I give command `autogen.sh` this shows output...

bash: autogen.sh: command not found

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does `autoreconf -i` work? Does the project have documentation about how to build from development sources (as opposed to a release tarball)? (Since I assume that's what you are doing as `configure` isn't there.)

Comment: where the documentation about how to build from dev sources? is it generally located inside the project? yes, configure isn't there. Just tried $ autoreconf -i ....shows following output.. autoreconf-2.69: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Comment: Yes, usually there is some documentation in the project. Often in a README or similar file if not on the project's website.

Comment: Where did you get this software from exactly? What does the current directory contain?

Comment: Actually, that name looks like a binary distribution. Are you sure you need to build anything? Is there a binary there alreadY?

Comment: For autoreconf -i ... is downloaded binary sufficient? or is source required? I am trying these commands on Cygwin terminal for the first time...also my first time to compile something into c++ world.

Comment: If you already have the binary of `xerces-c` then you are done. You don't need to build anything. You already *have* a working binary. Well... other then that that's a linux binary and probably won't work on Cygwin. Do they have a Cygwin or native Windows binary?

Comment: The command should be `path_to_autogen.sh`, if in the current directory, then `./autogen.sh`. The autogen.sh should be located in the downloaded source directory (where you are expecting the .configure to be built).

Comment: yes, i m using binaries. was following a tutorial(vichargrave.com/xml-parsing-with-dom-using-c/) in which it says to run ./configure which is missing. that's why all this

Comment: which correct file to download if i m using cygwin64 on windows..i used xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4.tar.gz from http://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/3/binaries/   am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Jahid - my current directory content looks like below... autogen.exe.stackdump  bin  CREDITS  doc  include  INSTALL  lib  LICENSE  NOTICE  README  samples

Comment: If you are trying to install the software, the installation instruction should be in the INSTALL file. You should read that first. You probably won't need the .configure file at all (as it seems a pre-built binary package). And also you can try finding a binary file that may resemble with your package name in the bin folder. If you can find it, then you will probably be able run it to launch the application.

Comment: @Etan - the site has xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-windows-vc-10.0.zip also but i was not sure which file to take and i m using cross-gcc toolchain. i took tar.gz file that was mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: That might be the right package for cygwin64. I don't know. You'd have to try it and see. And actually this is an XML library so there probably isn't a binary just a library under the `lib` directory that you are supposed to link against (and headers in `include`).

Comment: @Jahid - really sorry but i did not know what are the steps to use a downloaded project(didn't know that ./configure is not required for this). Now next step - Can i just import those packages into my .cpp file(like #include) or are there settings into eclipse for putting that into project libraries?

Comment: @Etan - the untarred file bin directory contents...i feel some compiled class files with no extension... CreateDOMDocument  DOMPrint  MemParse  PSVIWriter  SAX2Count  SAXCount  SCMPrint  StdInParse
DOMCount           EnumVal   PParse    Redirect    SAX2Print  SAXPrint  SEnumVal  XInclude

Comment: If those are libraries, you will probably be able to #include them with full paths (or link them with compiler options)...And the readme file generally contains instructions like this...

Comment: the README file refers to doc\html\index.html which is same as xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html ...

Comment: @Jahid - I can see that all required .hpp files in xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4\include\xercesc\parsers. But it shows inclusion errors in Eclipse on the lines of #include. any idea how to link them in eclipse?

Comment: @Etan - is the xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-windows-vc-10.0.zip for MSVC++ toolchain? cause I m not sure as you pointed too - whether the linux binary(xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4.tar.gz) will work on cygwin windows. hence confirming if I will have to use MSVC toolchain if I opt to use xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-windows-vc-10.0.zip.

Comment: I assume that version is built with/for/against MS VC++, yes. I would hope that Apache would have documentation for the library that would explain the toolchain/etc. requirements/issues for each binary build they provide.